# String matches() method not working properly

Tags: java, regex, string

So I have this method:

```
   void verifySecretKey(String userEnters, Scanner input){

    while(true) {
        System.out.print("Enter the secret key:  ");
        userEnters = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nVerifying Secret Key...");

        if (secretKey.matches(userEnters)) {
        System.out.println("Secret key verified!");
        break; } 

        else {
        System.out.println("The secret key does not follow the proper format!"); }
    }
}
```

and for some reason, it is not working properly. A string secretKey is automatically generated for the user and they must enter the exact string to be verified. However, even if the correct string was entered, it still says that it's incorrect.

[image]

Sometimes it works, and mostly it doesn't. I am wondering what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried with `.equals()` ?

Comment: Show the **text** of your input/output session, not a **picture** of it. That way, people can use copy and paste when testing, etc. (although in this case, it's clear what's wrong).

Answer (score 3):

[`String#matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) accepts a string defining a **regular expression**. If you want to check for equality, use `equals`, not `matches`.

`"oH-?bt-4#"` contains a `?`, which is a special character in regular expressions, not a literal `?`. So the string doesn't match the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Matches takes a regular expression as the argument. In the screenshot, you entered `oH-?bt-4#`, which contains a `?`. This character has a special meaning in a regex. If you want to use the `String#match` method, you have to escape all the special characters, e. g. using `Pattern.quote`:

```
if (secretKey.matches(Pattern.quote(userEnters))) //...
```

Since your goal seems to be to check whether the two strings are the same, you could just use the `String#equals` method:

```
if (secretKey.equals(userEnters)) //...
```

When you don't have a reason to choose the regex-method `matches`, you should stick with equals, since it's more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Javadoc,

> public boolean matches(String regex)
>
> Tells whether or not this string matches the given [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Now, `"Java".matches("Java")` is true, because the regex `Java` is a match for `Java`.

However there are lots of regexs that don't match themselves, and you're quite likely to find one if you generate strings randomly.

For example `"a+bc".matches("a+bc")` returns false -- because there's nothing there that matches the literal character `+` (`a+` matches one-or-more `a`s).

It's also very likely that a random string will result in something that can't be compiled as a regex, in which case your code will throw a `PatternSyntaxException` -- for example `a[bc` will do this because of an unmatched brace.

To test whether two strings are exactly the same, use `.equals()`.